# SQL Quiz SELECT / subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

Refer to the given SQL statement.

```
1. Select SPNAME 
2. FROM SALESPERSON 
3. Where SPNUM= 
4. FROM CUSTOMER 
5. WHERE CUSTNUM=20900);
```

What is missing from the subquery at the beginning of line 4?

```
(SELECT SPNUM
(SPNUM
(Subquery SPNUM
(FIND SPNUM
```

Comment: Do you have the table definitions for `SALESPERSON` and `CUSTOMER`?

Comment: sorry no that is exactly the way the question is written with no other info

Comment: The answer I gave is my best guess based on the info you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query should be `WHERE SPNUM = ...` or `WHERE SPNUM IN ...` followed by a subquery.  To be safe, we can use `WHERE SPNUM IN ...` in the event that the subquery return more than one record.

```
SELECT SPNAME
FROM SALESPERSON
WHERE SPNUM IN (SELECT SPNUM FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTNUM = 20900)
```